# Finding result of a recursive function

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

The given question is: "What is the value of `f 572` for the following definition of `f`?"

```
f :: Int -> Int
f n = g n (n+1)

g :: Int -> Int -> Int
g m i
    | (mod i m) == 0 = i
    | otherwise = g m (i+1)
```

To me this looks like a recursive function and the answer should be that the values keep adding up from `572` till `1044` (that's when `mod 1044 572` will be `0`).

Answer (score 1):

It is a very inefficient way to calculate the double `(2*)` of a number. Because you feed `g n (n+1)`.

`g` is given two numbers and as long as `(mod i m) == 0` fails (`i` is not dividable by `m`) it will **increment `i`**. From the moment it succeeds, it returns `i`. Now the lowest `n` larger than `k` that is dividable by `k` is obviously `2*k`.

So `f` is equivalent to:

```
-- equivalent to
f' = (2*)
```

In case **negative numbers are also considered**, it will always return `0`, for the strictly negative numbers since the first such number to satisfy the modulo relation is `0`. Finally if `0` is given, it will error. So when considering zero and negative numbers, the full definition is:

```
-- equivalent (with negative numbers and zero)
f' n | n > 0 = 2*n
     | n < 0 = 0
     -- n == 0 should error
```

Since the algorithm increments `i` each time, the program will run linear with `n` (given increment and modulo can be checked in constant time) so *O(n)*. The equivalent definition runs of course in constant time (given multiplication and comparisons can be done in constant time, this is not the case for `Integer` for instance).

Comment: ah yes i got it finally (thought a bit more), thanks.

Comment: @Sg587565: I also considered the case you give it negative numbers and zero.